# Extracting values from array nested inside array of objects in javscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array object like this:

```
const data =  [
    {
      name: "A",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 36,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 144,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "C",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 144,
        },
                {
          name: "FAIL",
          value: 256,
        },
      ],
    }]
```

I am trying to filter out the PASS objects from the data and create a new object which looks like this:

```
[
 {
   name: "A",
   value: 36,
 },
 {
   name: "B",
   value: 144,
 },
 {
   name: "C",
   value: 144,
 }
]
```

I tried to get the desired result this way this didn't work:

```
    sorted_obj = {}
    data.map(item => {
    item.values.map(registry => {
      if(registry.name === 'PASS'){
        sorted_obj.push({item.name:registry.name.value})
      }
    })
})
```

Please let me know where am I wrong or how can I achieve the desired result. Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Don't use map if you don't return something from it.

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of `map`, and `sorted_obj` should be an array(`[]`).

Comment: What if there are multiple `pass` items in the `values` array? Do you add them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` to iterate the `data` array. For every object in the `data` array, filter the `values` to include only items with "PASS" in the `name`. Now map the pass items, and use the `name` from the parent object:

```js
const data = [{"name":"A","values":[{"name":"PASS","value":36}]},{"name":"B","values":[{"name":"PASS","value":144}]},{"name":"C","values":[{"name":"PASS","value":144},{"name":"FAIL","value":256}]}]

const result = data.flatMap(o => 
  o.values.filter(v => v.name === 'PASS')
  .map(v => ({ 
    name: o.name,
    value: v.value,
  }))
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance considerations matter, I would opt for `Array.prototype.reduce()` (instead of `Array.prototype.flatMap()`), like that:

```js
const src = [{name:"A",values:[{name:"PASS",value:36}]},{name:"B",values:[{name:"PASS",value:144}]},{name:"C",values:[{name:"PASS",value:144},{name:"FAIL",value:256}]}]
    
const result = src.reduce((acc, {name, values}) => {
  const pass = values
    .filter(({name:_name}) => _name === 'PASS')
    .map(({value}) => ({name, value}))
  acc.push(...pass)
  return acc
}, [])    

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: I think this is overcomplicating it, the acc.push(...pass) mutates your acc object, and the reduction is unnecessary, a simple map would have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach, simple, short, and functional.

```js
const data = [{"name":"A","values":[{"name":"PASS","value":36}]},{"name":"B","values":[{"name":"PASS","value":144}]},{"name":"C","values":[{"name":"PASS","value":144},{"name":"FAIL","value":256}]}]

const results = data.map((grades)=>({name: grades.name, value: grades.values.find(value => value.name === 'PASS').value}))

console.log(results)
```

Comment: I would have few concerns about robustness here: first off, we're not sure whether there's always a single _passing_ item within `values` sub array (if that's not the case only first match will be returned here). My second concern - if there are no _passing_ items at all, you'll get items, like `{name: X}` in the resulting array and I'm not really sure if this is desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data =  [
    {
      name: "A",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 36,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 144,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "C",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 144,
        },
        {
          name: "FAIL",
          value: 256,
        },
      ],
    }
];
    
const sorted_obj = [];
data.map(item => {
  item.values.map(registry => {
    if(registry.name === 'PASS'){
      sorted_obj.push({name: item.name, value: registry.value})
    }
  });
});
console.log(sorted_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply with one [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), and a bit of [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const data=[{name:"A",values:[{name:"PASS",value:36}]},{name:"B",values:[{name:"PASS",value:144}]},{name:"C",values:[{name:"PASS",value:144},{name:"FAIL",value:256}]}];

const out = [];

// For each object in the data array extract
// the name and values properties
for (let { name, values } of data) {

  // Find the object in values which has a PASS value
  // and return that value
  const value = values.find(({ name }) => name === 'PASS').value;

  // Push a new object with those properties
  // to your array
  out.push({ name, value });
}

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following works by first extracting the values then flattening them to create a flat list of all the values. That list can then be filtered using the Array.filter method.

Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```js
const data =  [
    {
      name: "A",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 36,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 144,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "C",
      values: [
        {
          name: "PASS",
          value: 144,
        },
                {
          name: "FAIL",
          value: 256,
        },
      ],
    }];
    
    const allNestedValues = data
    .map(obj => obj.values.map(value => ({...value, objName: obj.name}))) //extract the nested values
    .reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []); //create a flattened list of values
    
    const passingNestedValues = allNestedValues
    .filter(value => value.name === 'PASS') //filter to allow just PASS
    .map(value => ({name:value.objName, value:value.value}))//extract desired properties
    console.log(passingNestedValues);
```

Comment: This solution returns an incorrect answer.